# Не работает forEach в некоторых браузерах

Tags: javascript

В некоторых браузерах не работает forEach. Как можно переписать этот код?

```
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var navs = document.querySelectorAll('#js-navigation div');
for( var i = 0; i < navs.length; i++ ){
    navs[i].addEventListener('click', selectMenu(i), false);
}

function selectMenu(iterator) {
    return function() {
        var parents = document.querySelectorAll('#js-navigation div');
        parents.forEach(function(item, iter) {
            item.classList.remove('active');

            if(iterator == iter) {
                item.classList.add('active');
            }
        });

        var topMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.ntk-top-menu');

        topMenu.forEach(function(item, iter) {
            item.classList.add('hide');
           if(iterator == iter) {
               item.classList.remove('hide');
           }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Тут можно использовать `for()`. Но как сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый обычный цикл for по длине элементов.

```
...
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('#js-navigation div');
for(var iter = 0; iter < parents.length; iter++){
    parents[iter].classList.remove('active');
    if(iterator == iter) {
        parents[iter].classList.add('active');
    }
}
...
var topMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.ntk-top-menu');
for(var iter = 0; iter < topMenu.length; iter++){
    topMenu[iter].classList.add('hide');
    if(iterator == iter) {
        topMenu[iter].classList.remove('hide');
    }
}
...
```

Comment: спасибо, все было элементарно

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть справку, то [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает не массив, а *NodeList*.

Поддержка [метода *forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) у этой коллекции пока оставляет желать лучшего.

Большинство методов из *Array.prototype*, такие как `map`,`forEach` и т.д. имеют обобщенную реализацию и могут применяться не только к массивам.

Для их непосредственного применения можно пользоваться [методом `call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(navs, function(){...})
[].forEach.call(navs, function(){...})
```

Кроме этого их можно добавить коллекции

```
if(!navs.forEach){
    navs.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Следующие варианты: привести коллекцию к массиву. Раньше это делали с помощью [метода `slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var navsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(navs);
```

сейчас же можно применять функцию [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) и [spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
Array.from(navs).forEach(...)
[...navs].forEach(...)
```

А так же никуда не уходит цикл [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), к которому сейчас добавляется цикл [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: сначала сделала так `Array.prototype.forEach.call` но такое решение не понравилось)

Comment: почему не понравилось?

Comment: некоторым коллегам не понравилось) советовали использовать `for` который поддеживается всеми браузерами

Comment: а они как-нибудь обосновывали _почему_ им не понравилось? как ни странно _forEach_ тоже уже поддерживается всеми браузерами

Comment: нет, не всеми поддерживается. FF 49-й версии не поддерживает и Chrome 48-й на Ubuntu не поддерживает.  и сама конструкция `Array.prototype.forEach.call` не понравилась.

Comment: Не путай `Array.prototype.forEach` и `NodeList.forEach` - это разные функции.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ)